# Weird Output Value: b'[value]\r\n' - Python Serial Read

Tags: python, serial-port

I'm reading a value through Python from the serial port of a sensor of Arduino.

My code(Python):

```
arduino = serial.Serial(2, 9600, timeout=1)
print("Message from arduino: ") 
while True:
   msg = arduino.readline()
   print(msg)
```

I don't know why the output result is something like `b'[sensor-value]\r\n'`. 
So, I get something like `b'758\r\n'` `b'534\r\n'` `b'845\r\n'` etc (regarding to sensor change value).

How I convert this?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You need to decode it.

```
print(msg.decode('utf-8'))
```

Please check [Lexical Analysis](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/lexical_analysis.html#literals) on Python 3 documentation to see what string prefixes means

Comment: Now it's working! Thanks a million! I knew it was simple, but I don't even knew how to search for the solution.

Comment: FYI:  This decoding was/is not necessary with Python 2.7

Answer (score 0):

Encountered a similar problem with a Raspberry Pi Pico where I needed to both decode and get rid of the extra characters. That can all be achieved with a one-liner. This relies on the `pySerial` package.

```
msg = ser.readline().decode('utf-8').rstrip()
```

For the above example, `serial.Serial` has been named `arduino` instead of `ser`, so the solution there would simply be:

```
msg = arduino.readline().decode('utf-8').rstrip()
```

Found the hint in this [blog post](https://roboticsbackend.com/raspberry-pi-arduino-serial-communication/).